# Regular expression takes bounds into group

Tags: java, regex

I want to group some characters between special symbol bounds, but this bounds are involved into group. It is not connected with greedy and reluctant quantifier.

```
String str1 = "#162xd14a#";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#(.*?)#").matcher(str1);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
#162xd14a#
```

But i expected:

```
162xd14a
```

Comment: you can also use lookbehinds and lookaheads like `(?<=#)(.*?)(?=#)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official tutorial about [Capturing Groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

> There is also a special group, group 0, which always represents the entire expression. This group is not included in the total reported by groupCount.

In the context of your example:

- Group 0 contains the entire matched string, `#162xd14a#`
- Group 1 contains the first (and only) matched group: `162xd14a`
- You have one group in your regex, therefore `groupCount()` returns 1
- The loop stops before reaching group 1, because of the `<` condition

You probably want to change the loop condition to `<=` instead of `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```